# making a array of objects that can have variable amount of elements

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am trying to make a class to handle my user database for a programming school project. This will be using arrays and not arraylist which is a core parameter of the assignment.

```
public class UserDB {
    User[] UserAry;

    public UserDB(){
        UserAry = new User[0];
    }

    //admin
    public void addUser(String id, String pw, char type){
        User[] NewUserAry = new User[UserAry.length+1];
        for (int i=0; i<UserAry.length;i++){
            NewUserAry[i] = UserAry[i];
        }
        NewUserAry[NewUserAry.length-1] = new User(id,pw,type);
        UserAry = NewUserAry;
    }



}
```

This is the code. I'm worried that if i were to call this in another class, then the array would always be at 0(when i call UserDB) or 1 (when i add a new user it would add one to previous zero) , before the arraysize becomes to zero again since it is initialized as 0.

Comment: This looks like working code. Can you be more specific about your issue? Maybe you have a misunderstanding about how Java works in some way?

Comment: So, what r u struggling for ?

Comment: *"before the arraysize becomes to zero again since it is initialized as 0"* Why would it become zero? Why would it be initialized as 0? That only happens when you create a new instance of `UserDB`, so don't create a new one, keep using the first one you created. Of course, that all happens in code you haven't shown, so we can't help much there.

Comment: i havent started on making the code i havent shown actually. i am still working on making the classes to use during the actual main code. I think i may be misunderstanding how the code/Java works so i was panicking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any problem with your code. Just for the sake of making it cleaner, I have replaced your `for` loop with `System.arraycopy`. Apart from that, I have also replaced the variable names following the naming convention. Given below is the working code:

```
public class User {
    String id,pw;
    char type;
    public User(String id, String pw, char type) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.pw = pw;
        this.type = type;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", pw=" + pw + ", type=" + type + "]";
    }
}

public class UserDB {
    User[] userAry;

    public UserDB() {
        userAry = new User[0];
    }

    public void addUser(String id, String pw, char type) {
        User[] newUserAry = new User[userAry.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(userAry, 0, newUserAry, 0, userAry.length);
        newUserAry[newUserAry.length - 1] = new User(id, pw, type);
        userAry = newUserAry;
    }
    public void printList() {
        for (User user:userAry)
            System.out.println(user);
    }
}

public class TestUserDB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserDB db=new UserDB();
        db.addUser("a1", "a", 'a');
        db.addUser("a2", "b", 'b');
        db.addUser("a3", "c", 'a');
        db.addUser("a4", "d", 'b');

        db.printList();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
User [id=a1, pw=a, type=a]
User [id=a2, pw=b, type=b]
User [id=a3, pw=c, type=a]
User [id=a4, pw=d, type=b]
```

Comment: and also renamed userAry with lower case name

Comment: no, everything is fine I just mean that you not only changed for loop to arraycopy, but also renamed userAry which should begin with lover case